# Spring MVC Thymeleaf: th:field gives error at testing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, thymeleaf

I use Spring MVC with Thymeleaf. I created a Thymeleaf page, and it works correctly (in my browser). Now I try to test it with the [Thymeleaf test library](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-testing), but it gives a error at the `SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor`, it happends at the first input field he sees. The problem is with the `th:field="*{username}"`, (the test continues when I remove all the `th:fields`).

What am I doing wrong?

Thymeleafs test file:

```
%CONTEXT
user = new [...].User()

# ------------------------------------------
%INPUT 
<span layout:include="page :: content" th:remove="tag"></span>

%INPUT[page] (file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/views/CreateNewUser.html)

# ------------------------------------------
%OUTPUT
<Some HTML />
```

Part of the form:

```
<form action="#" 
    th:action="@{/spring/CreateNewUser}"
    th:object="${user}" method="post">

<input type="text" th:field="*{username}" />

<button type="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
```

The error is:

```
  |  ERROR [TemplateEngine] [THYMELEAF][main] Exception processing template "C:\[..]\test-classes\thymeleaftest\CreateNewUser.thtest-001": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (page:60)
[2014-07-21 09:51:21][RTJ8C0][main] [test:end][C:\[...]\target\test-classes\thymeleaftest\CreateNewUser.thtest-001][529208814][KO] Test FAILED: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (page:60) Time: 529208814ns (529ms).
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (page:60)
```

Comment: You're passing a `user` object to `th:object`, but you defined it as `userObject` in the context.

Comment: I checked it, but apparently I made a mistake while rewriting the test file to make the question clearer. Thanks anyway!